# Android Studio can't move .android folder to specific location

Tags: android, macos

I've read a lot of topics about Android Studio in Windows, but I can't make it for Android Studio in OSX. Obviously I'm using Android Studio 2.2.3 and Mac OSX Sierra.

I've tried to set ANDROID_SDK_HOME and ANDROID_AVD_HOME in my ~/.bash_profile, but when I run my project on Android Studio, .android folder keeps in wrong location (It still created at /Users/username/.android folder).

Is there someone with the same problem and could share your solution?

Thank you sincerely.

[bash_profile configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKAml.png)

Answer (score 0):

Based on information that I read, OSX use different environment variable setting between terminal and launchd.

I finally got it worked by create launchd plist file inside ~/Library/LaunchAgents/. You can pick random file name with .plist extension, in my case I named it androidstudio.plist.

Below is the content of the file (androidstudio.plist):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>my.startup</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>sh</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>launchctl setenv ANDROID_AVD_HOME /Volumes/Data/Android/.android/avd; launchctl setenv ANDROID_SDK_HOME /Volumes/Data/Android</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```